# How to remove new lines from a multi-lined paragraph in python?

Tags: python

I have a para with multiple lines. I need to remove new lines and make it like a single line string.

Comment: replace the newline chars?

Comment: Whats preventing you from doing this? All of the methods for manipulating strings are well documented.

Comment: Usually a paragraph is what is between line breaks. If you have an other definition, please add some sample input and the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

`text.replace("\n", "")`

Just replaces newline chars. Do be careful: sometimes you may also need to filter `\r` as well, as some OSs use both.

Comment: text.replace("/n", "").replace( "/r","" ) if you share code or parse files from windows and mac/linux